# Let $\left<M,||.|| \right>$ be a normed vector space then $G = \{x \in M \mid \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

> Let $\left<M,||.|| \right>$ be a normed vector space, show that $G = \{x \in M \mid
> \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is closed.

My strategy is to show $G^c$ is open.

Let $\rho$ be the metric of $M$ and $G^c=\left\{x \in M \  \middle| \ \  \Vert x \Vert  >1 \right\}$

Let $r = \Vert{x}\Vert -1 \gt 0$

Let $y \in B_r(x)$ then $\rho(x,y) \lt r \iff \rho(x,y) \lt \Vert x \Vert - 1$

By triangle inequality of metrics,

$\rho(x,0) \leq \rho(x,y) + \rho(y,0)$

$\implies \Vert x \Vert \lt \Vert x \Vert - 1 + \rho(0,y)$

$\iff 1 \lt \rho(0,y)$

$\iff \Vert y \Vert \gt 1$

$\implies y \in G^c \implies B_r(x) \subset G^c  \implies G^c$ is open
$\implies G$ is closed $\ \ \ \Box$

The basis of my proof is that norm of vector $x$ is the metric between $x$ and the $0$ vector. Is this okay?

Comment: Looks ok to me !

Comment: It's good, and I'm not sure what you're worried about. Are you worried that you shouldn't be using facts about metric spaces to prove something about norms? If so, then don't forget that norms have their own (axiomatic) triangle inequality which works just as well.

Comment: I wasn't sure if $\Vert x \Vert$ translated to $\rho(x,0)$. I deduced this only from reading somewhere that "norm of a vector is just a distance from the origin" written in a somewhat informal way. Yes, I am aware of the triangle inequality in normed vector spaces as well. I'll see if I can try to use that.

Comment: @Sunny Your intuition about normed spaces and metric spaces is all fine. You're right that it's an informal way of reasoning, and your proof does take for granted the fact that there exists a metric $\rho$ such that $\rho(x, 0) = \|x\|$. There is such a metric: $\rho(x, y) = \|x - y\|$. If you haven't yet proven that this is a metric, then I suggest translating everything back to norms.